# Apache Mina SSH: Client to interact with the server

Tags: java, ssh, apache-mina

I am writing a program where I can send a shell command to the server and work on its response. I looked at this [TestCase](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/sshd/trunk/sshd-core/src/test/java/org/apache/sshd/ClientTest.java) (testClient()) and managed to connect and send some commands. However I receive the response only after the call to `channel.waitFor(ClientChannel.CLOSED, 0);` and this method returns only when "exit" has been sent to the server.

How can I make a normal SSH interaction as if I am using PUTTY but have java do something with the response like for example, cd to a folder, list the files, if an interesting folder is found cd to that folder, if a file with a certain filename is found, do some grep, etc etc?

Comment: I think i got it by using channel.waitFor(ClientChannel.STDOUT_DATA, millis); It's just that I have to set something in "millis" which I'm a bit uncomfortable and unsure how manny millis to put in there.